# Get dates in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Good day,

I'm trying to get the dates 'older than 2 months from now' and 'younger than six months from now' in my doctrine query builder.

What I currently have is;

```
if ($type == 'older_than_two_months') {
    $qb->andWhere('i.createdAt < ');
}
if ($type == 'younger_than_six_months') {
    $qb->andWhere('i.createdAt > ');
}

$qb->orderBy('i.createdAt', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter('status', $status);
```

Do I just have to add an extra parameter? But I don't know how to get the date of a few months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually very simple with the PHP DateTime's:

```
if ($type == 'older_than_two_months') {
    $qb->andWhere('i.createdAt < :olderThan')
        ->setParameter('olderThan', new \DateTime('-2 months'));
}
if ($type == 'younger_than_six_months') {
    $qb->andWhere('i.createdAt > :youngerThan')
        ->setParameter('olderThan', new \DateTime('-6 months'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($type == 'older_than_two_months') {
    $qb->andWhere('f.dateAdded < :twoMonthsAgo')
    $qb->setParameter(':twoMonthsAgo', (new \DateTime())->modify('-2months'))
}
if ($type == 'younger_than_six_months') {
    $qb->andWhere('f.dateAdded > :sixMonthsAgo')
    $qb->setParameter(':sixMonthsAgo', (new \DateTime())->modify('-6months'))
}
```